# CollectionOperation GET|POST with nested path not possible anymore?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

During migration from API-Platform 2.4 to 3.2 we encountered the following problem:

In version 2.4 it was possible to declare a collection endpoint with a nested path - e.g. /books/invoice

After migration to API-Platform 3.2 I get a 404 error when calling this endpoint.

Are nested paths without parameters not allowed anymore?

Declaration before migration:

```
/**
 * API Entity "Book"
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *        "get"={},
 *        "post"={},
 *        "get_invoice"={
 *           "method"="GET",
 *           "path"="/books/invoice",
 *           "swagger_context"={
 *              "summary"="Gets all books that have not yet been invoiced"
 *           }
 *        }
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *        "get"={},
 *        "put"={},
 *        "delete"={}
 *     }
 * )
 */
```

Code after migration:

```
/**
 * API Entity "Book"
 */
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new Put(),
        new Delete(),
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post(),
        new GetCollection(
            uriTemplate: '/books/invoice',
            provider: BookInvoiceProvider::class,
            openapi: new Operation(
                summary: 'Gets all books that have not yet been invoiced',
            )
        )
    ]
)]
```

The debug:router commands shows
`_api/books/invoice_get_collection  GET  ANY  ANY  /api/books/invoice`

But the router matches the single GET endpoint

```
php bin/console router:match /api/books/invoice

[OK] Route "_api_/books/{id}{._format}_get" matches
```

Changing uriTemplate to "books_invoice" would solve the issue. But I was wondering why it doesn't work anymore.